# How to get the number of columns in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I specify a matrix `A` like

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

how can I query `A` **(without using `length(A)`)** to find out it has 3 columns?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the [`size()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function.

```
>> size(A,2)

Ans =

   3
```

The second argument specifies the dimension of which number of elements are required which will be '2' if you want the number of columns.

[Official documentation.](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)

Comment: I think it is generally a good practice to avoid using `length()` on matrices and use `size()` instead. when using `length()` you have to assume what is the largest dimension, and I have encountered too many bugs where this assumption was not correct.

Comment: @Scottie what does 2 stand for?

Comment: @gbox 2 stands for the second dimension of the matrix, i.e., the number of columns. `size(A,1)` will give you the number of rows.

Answer (score 10):

While `size(A,2)` is correct, I find it's much more readable to first define

```
rows = @(x) size(x,1); 
cols = @(x) size(x,2);
```

and then use, for example, like this:

```
howManyColumns_in_A = cols(A)
howManyRows_in_A    = rows(A)
```

It might appear as a small saving, but `size(.., 1)` and `size(.., 2)` must be some of the most commonly used functions, and they are not optimally readable as-is.

Answer (score 5):

When want to get **row size** with **size()** function, below code can be used:

```
size(A,1)
```

Another usage for it:

```
[height, width] = size(A)
```

So, you can get 2 dimension of your matrix.

Comment: plese do not leave comments as answers.

Comment: As a noob to Octave, thank you for writing this out in a way that makes it easy to read.

Comment: The row size was not the question here. Upvote *only* for `[height, width] = size(A)`